# Html5 Canvas drawing problem

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing, paint

The trouble is - when I mousedown, then mousemove(about 1-2px), the point, which I draw disappears. It is because I clear context each mousemove, but I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Why can't you just remove the `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 592, 294);`

Comment: Could you clarify your goal? Is it your intent for only the last line to be shown, or for all the lines to be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what the problem is, but I think the problem is that rounding is causing your new line to not be a full pixel and thus empty.  Could this be the problem?  If so the solution is to make the move just a little bigger if it is small.